# polynomial equation with non-integer powers

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

If for every $t$ $$\sum_{i=0}^{k_1}\left[\left(a_i^Tx-b_i\right)t^i\right]=0$$
where $a_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}, \forall 
i \in \{0,\dots, k_1\}$, and $b_i \in \mathbb{R}$, then
$$Ax=b$$
where the rows of $A$ are the vectors $a_i^T$ and the components of $b$ are the values $b_i$, $\forall 
i \in \{0,\dots, k_1\}$.

For the case $$\sum_{i=0}^{k_1}\left[\left(a_i^Tx-b_i\right)t^i\right]+t^\lambda\sum_{i=0}^{k_2}\left[\left(c_i^Tx-d_i\right)t^i\right]=0$$
where $\lambda$ is not an integer, can we form a similar system of equations? For example, 
$$\left[\begin{matrix} 
A \\
C
\end{matrix}\right]x=\left[\begin{matrix} 
b \\
d
\end{matrix}\right]$$
where the rows of $C$ are the vectors $c_i^T$ and the components of $d$ are the values $d_i$, $\forall 
i \in \{0,\dots, k_2\}$?

Comment: so a [Piseux series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series) with infinitely many coefficients 0 ?

Comment: That's correct.